# Can Trello auto-number list items and display the order in the list on the card, and update when the card moves?

Tags: trello

Is there any way to have the list "item number" appear on the card?  I have a lot of things to keep track of, and seeing an actual "#45 Action" would be very useful - even more so if it would "re-calculate" based on where on the list I drag the item too

---

Let me re-phrase the original question... I just want to see list item # as an option to show / hide in the title of the card.  When I move the card to the top of a list, it displays "#1 My Card Title" and when I move it to 5th on my list it displays "#5 My Card Title"

Comment: Can you make a screen shot to further elaborate on what you mean? It's hard to visualize what you're going for here. Also, check out the resources page at https://trello.com/resources.

Answer (score 2):

Each card has a card number which roughly translates to when it was added. For example, the card [Subscribe](https://trello.com/card/subscribe/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/1049) on the Trello Development board is number 1049, which means it was roughly the 1049th card added to the board. The card number is visible in the bottom right of the back of a card.

There's no way to change or recalculate the card number. You might try just changing the title, though that can be a lot of work.

[image]

EDIT: Here is a screenshot from the latest version of Trello

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% the thing you want, but close to is the following solution:

If you click on a card, you can get the number of the card in the list by doing the following:

- At the bottom right of the card you see the action-panel.
- If you click at "move" or "copy" a sub-window opens. You can see there the current position of the card in this list (at the place, where you select the destination).

I use this for example if I want to figure out, how many items are in one list.

Answer (score 0):

**[Trello Card Numbers](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/trello-card-numbers/kadpkdielickimifpinkknemjdipghaf)** is what you're looking for.

This adds card numbers to Trello cards to help when viewing/discussing boards with a group of people. Trello actually includes card numbers but hides them by default.

This extension does the following:

Reveals card numbers on cards themselves

- Reveals the card count for a given list
- Adds a card number to a created card
- Adds a card number head in the detail view
- Allows you to make card numbers bold
- Allows you to change the color of the card numbers

This extension **doesn't update the numbers when you move the card**, but it could be useful for you.